# How to group List of integer in Scala

Tags: scala

I have list as follow

```
 List[Int] = List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478, 51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
```

I want to group this list into sub-list as follow

```
 List1[Int] = List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478)
```

and

```
 List2[Int] = List(51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
```

By referring fist two digit of each and every elements of list(In here it is 50 and 51).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupBy`:

```
val x = List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478, 51176477, 51176483, 51176480)

x.groupBy(_.toString.take(2))
```

Here `_.toString.take(2)` is used to make groups. You can use any function that returns 2 first digits of number, even without conversion to String.

Result:

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(51 -> List(51176477, 51176483, 51176480), 50 -> List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478))
```

If you want just lists, use `.values`:

```
x.groupBy(_.toString.take(2)).values


res0: Iterable[List[Int]] = MapLike(List(51176477, 51176483, 51176480), List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter on the list which checks the first two digits of every number in your list:

```
val list = List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478, 51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
val list1 = list.filter(_.toString.substring(0, 2) == "50")
val list2 = list.filter(_.toString.substring(0, 2) == "51")
println(list1)
println(list2)
```

**Output:**

```
List(50176482, 50176481, 50176485, 50176479, 50176478)
List(51176477, 51176483, 51176480)
```

## Demo